# Using a Schengen type D visa for a short internship in a different country

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, belgium

I have a “France sauf CTOM” Trainee visa type D, validated with OFII Permit. It is valid from 01/Nov/14 to 01/Nov/15. I did an internship in France for 6 months from Nov 14 to May 15.

Now currently I am in India and I would like to pursue an internship in Belgium  using this visa from September 2015 to end of October 2015. Will it be a problem? I think it won't since the long term D visa is valid for a maximum of 3 months in a period of 180 days.

Answer (score 1):

As far as **visas** are concerned, a type D visa gives you rights similar to a type C short-stay visa to be present in Shengen *outside* the issuing state for 90 of every 180 days.

However, also like a short-stay visa it does not give you any right to **work** outside the issuing state. The Belgian authorities may consider your internship to be work (I don't know how they define it, but it is rarely just a question of whether you get paid or not), in which case you could get into trouble quite independently of the visa situation.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply,its not paid but only small bonus(not salaried) ,i hope in this case it will be fine ,let me know,the intern ship is only for two months.

Comment: @divyanshuSingh: As I wrote, I don't know what the Belgian rules are. You need to be in contact with the Belgian authorities, not random people on the internet.